# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/mxoemeygmlk?file=app%2Ftable-http-example.ts

What is the best solution for this angular error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution (hack) I know for this is to use `setTimeout(function , 0)` which will send your function to the end of the event loop until angular finishes its checking, something like this:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.ngAfterViewInitUtil(), 0);
  }
  ngAfterViewInitUtil(){
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDao(this.http);
    // The rest of the code
```

Also notice that this error will happen only in development mode and will not happen in production mode as angular will not recheck the state of the application in production mode.

You can read more about this error in [this page](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: I just read the article and I still have doubts, since there is no solution, but hacks. My actual solution is call ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges after change in variable.

Comment: I don't think it's worth it, since this error is to ensure the stability of the model (which we know your model is) so IMHO there is no need to complicate the code. If you want the code to be readable for other coders, you can wrap the setTimeout in a function with a descriptive name.

Answer (score 1):

using **setTimeout** is not right way to solve this problem
you should use

**ChangeDetectorRef**

```
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
  ngOnInit(){
  this.chu.checkShow.subscribe( value => {
      // do something
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I just add the this.cdr.detectChanges() on the line of code where I know the value changes and then I don't get the error anymore.